# Is Oracle Coherence stable?

Tags: oracle, distributed-caching, oracle-coherence

Has anyone used [Oracle Coherence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index.html)? It looks very promising at the roadshows.

My concern is whether it's a stable and robust enough to implement mission-critical financial solutions.

I'd be grateful for any feedback on its performance, robustness and ease of maintenance.

Answer (score 11):

I've had first hand experience with Oracle Coherence at two big investment banks and can say it's definitely stable. However, as with any complex piece of software it's not without it's quirks.

**EDIT:** Doh, just realised the question is over a year old. Oh well...

Comment: But there will always be people like me that come here looking for an answer even a year after. Thanks for your answer. By the way: what are the major quirks you remember?

Answer (score 6):

Coherence is in production at hundreds of companies. Many of the companies are large financial institutions and large consumer websites. For example, [hotwire.com](http://www.hotwire.com/) uses Coherence.

Answer (score 2):

As with any technology, Coherence has the capability to meet your needs for performance and robustness. If you understand the technology and implement it correctly, then yes.

I've been using it for a few months now. So far, it's doing fine in production. We haven't gotten to the maintenance part yet.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Coherence is a mature product, but you need to make sure that you have the latest patches from Oracle.  The point releases that are downloadable from the Oracle website have many bugs that are fixed in the patch releases.

As for development and maintenance, the learning curve is a little steeper than the documentation would suggest.  I recommend the Oracle training course (or Alek Seovic's book).